# How much code is visible to JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

As every java application needs the main method except the case of applets and web application where the main method is implemented by web container so as the main method is starting point of the program as we pass the name of the class including main with java command to execute it.

---

So my question is how much code is visible to JVM means does it sees the whole code or it loads classes or information it came across during execution of the program.
Maybe my question is out of context, but please clear it.

Comment: Classes are loaded from the classpath only when needed, lazily, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: that actually depends on the classloader. some classloaders could conceivably be eager, maybe for reflection purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java loads classes "on demand". As soon as you somehow "use" X, X.class is loaded. Please note: "using" is more than just "importing" within source code.

You can find a nice introduction to this topic [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/when-and-how-a-java-class-is-loaded-and-initialized/).

And, as Holger points out correctly: you have to distinguish between *loading* and *initialization* time.

Comment: It’s worth emphasizing that the *loading* time is not equivalent to the *initialization* time. The *loading* time is implementation specific and JVMs are free to eagerly preload classes referenced by a class file. The *initialization* happens at [exactly specified points](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1). In the [most commonly used JVM implementation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), most classes are loaded shortly before initialization, except for the few cases where earlier loading is required by the Verifier.